# Can implexion be a nonwell-founded relation?

Tags: set-theory, objects

Alexius Meinong's "doctrine" of implexion is that there are complete and incomplete objects and that the latter are "implected in" the former ([see the SEP article on that](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/#TheForFurInv)).

Can this be represented as a descending membership chain, infinite in scope? Where each element down the line is implected in its successor (predecessor)? I was trying to model types as heads of such chains, but the SEP article says that Meinong possibly concluded that universals are the incomplete things, which (if types are universals) goes against that model. Still, I feel that an object is conceivable that has infinite degrees of incompleteness, and it *seems* then that we can descend from the complete to the incomplete.

So can some relations of implexion be nonwell-founded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/#TheForFurInv) you link to, "implexion is a relation between incomplete and complete objects". Complete objects are rock bottom (that is, you cannot further complete them), so it would seem as if a chain based on the implexion operator could only have two members.

That doesn't mean that you can't define your own operator based on Meinongian implexion, of course, if it does useful work in your theory of types.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if, "C is implected in B, and B is implected in A," fits the idea, whether the relation would be transitive or well-founded (is A maximal or minimal?), whether it can "go on forever"... I'mma upvote your answer for now, ✔️ it in a little if I don't think of any objections to it.

Comment: The kind of construction that (I think) you have in mind is probably coherent and can be formalized; it's just also probably not true to implexion as defined by Meinong. But that's not super important, if it's useful and illuminating when thinking about types!

Comment: The most progress I've made is: with respect to the surreal numbers, ω - 1 is implected in ω, ω - 2 is implected in ω - 1, etc. That "looks right." But I can't get what I want from this (a large cardinal expressed as an implexion function) as the <\> relations are different for surreal numbers.